# Partially Immutable infrastructure in AWS with Packer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, packer

I'm a very young systems engineer/contractor sysadmin with a bandwidth-heavy workload that just moved to an area where I get 2mbps download and 20 upload on my internet connection. I'm moving my Debian 10 workstation to AWS because of that, and I need some advice.

I want to manage my workstation setup with terraform (99% done), packer, and ansible. I want to create a script to run every time I change my ansible setup that will create a new AMI with packer+ansible and deploy it with Terraform.

I want to keep my home directory the same in all versions of my infrastructure since I have a ton of vagrant boxes and pip venvs populated with packages that I want to have consistent no matter what the base system configuration is. The home directory will be slightly managed as I add ssh keys, create a hotwired vagrant setup (which is worthy of another post), etc. That is the main roadblock right now.

I was thinking about using a second EBS volume and mounting it at /home/. The issue with that is when you create an AMI from another instance, it will copy the EBS, and get its own EBS ID. The next time I create an AMI with Packer, I will need to snapshot, attach, and mount the EBS volume on the running instance and I don't see a clear way to do that with Packer or Ansible. EFS is too slow to consider.

Basically, what is a way to keep data from the production instance when moving to a new instance in AWS without creating an ami from the older instance, while avoiding slow or expensive components such as EFS. I can't just ami-create a new instance because I want my AMI's to be generated from the base Debian 10 image to prevent configuration drift.

Comment: Do you have to build the new AMI with the second EBS volume attached or can you build it with an empty `/home`? You can then attach the additional volume to the new instance when you boot it with Terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a left field answer, and probably won't be accepted, but I think it's an option worth mentioning. Please avoid the urge to vote me down because I'm not answering exactly as expected.

Using EFS is probably best practice. It's a bit more expensive with a bit more latency, but it's good for this task.

**AWS Workspaces**

Have you considered [AWS Workspaces](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/)? It's Ubuntu, but might solve your problem of a cloud based workstation.

**S3 Storage**

Storage on S3 is cheap, and usually fast enough, especially if you have an S3 gateway in your VPC.

Your two main options with S3 are:

- Use [S3FS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount an S3 bucket as storage, with an S3 gateway in the VPC you should get acceptable performance
- Sync your data with S3 on startup, shutdown, and you could do it with cron as well. I believe bandwidth to S3 is free when you use a VPC gateway, but you still pay for the put / get operations, which should be a fairly low cost.

Comment: The more I'm looking at this problem, the more I like EFS. Its much slower than EBS but it's independence from the VM itself would make it really easy. Thank you for your time on this answer.

Comment: Upvote if you like it, and mark it as the answer if you go that way :)

Comment: I did upvote it, my upvotes don't count until I have 15 reputation. Marked as answer :)

Comment: Great, hope it helped :) EFS might be a bit more expensive but is pretty much ideal for what you need. S3FS is less reliable but could make the storage cheaper.